# How can you verify when a drive was last formatted?

Tags: disk-utility, apfs, disk-format

I'm trying to determine the date a drive on a MacBook was last formatted. I used to be able check the inode birth time of the root volume, but it appears a recent MacOS update may have changed this behaviour because I'm now seeing Jan 1 2020 anytime I check via

```
stat -f "Access (atime): %Sa%nModify (mtime): %Sm%nChange (ctime): %Sc%nBirth  (Btime): %SB" /
Access (atime): Jan  1 03:00:00 2020
Modify (mtime): Jan  1 03:00:00 2020
Change (ctime): Jan  1 03:00:00 2020
Birth  (Btime): Jan  1 03:00:00 2020
```

I'm aware I can simply check the software installation dates, but that doesn't necessarily indicate if the drive was actually formatted or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of what's causing that `stat` behaviour — are you using Big Sur? On a drive formatted with Catalina, `stat` reports the correct value.

In any case, you can use my tool [Drat](https://github.com/jivanpal/drat) to see the timestamps of all APFS volumes. Do `diskutil apfs list` to find the block device that represents the "Physical Store", e.g. in the following output...

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 9FB9190C-8782-48FB-956E-0539C73996ED
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      479894224896 B (479.9 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   409366626304 B (409.4 GB) (85.3% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       70527598592 B (70.5 GB) (14.7% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 44F7C60F-6302-4F08-A1A4-40F7BAA25D12
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       479894224896 B (479.9 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 68FF83AF-C326-4C78-ABDA-C33E52D07D29
    |   ---------------------------------------------------

[...]
```

... the Physical Store is `disk0s2`, which corresponds to the block device `/dev/disk0s2`.

Then use Drat to inspect the physical store, e.g. `drat inspect /dev/disk0s2`. Included in the output for each volume is "Formatted by:" and "Last modified by:". All times are in UTC. For example:

```
[...]

Volume name:        ### macOS ###
Role:               System (contains a root directory for the system)
Flags:
- Volume is unencrypted.

[...]

Formatted by:
- ID: diskmanagementd (1412.41.1)
- Timestamp: Sat Nov 23 11:18:26 2019
- Last XID: 25

Last modified by:
- ID: apfs_kext (1412.141.1)
- Timestamp: Mon Feb 15 10:22:49 2021
- Last XID: 5d644b

[...]
```